# How to reduce database query when using stateless framework like Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I just moved to Spring MVC for several days. Before that, I used to develop web project using JSF, EJB and JPA.

In EJB, we can use a stateful session bean(SFSB) with **extended persistence context** so that I can cache the entities in order to reduce database query. But in Spring MVC, once the entity is returned from a @Service bean, it becomes detached and cannot survive the next request. So I have to query database again in next request.

My question is how can I keep an entity managed by Entitymanager during many request?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a 2nd level cache or session scoped beans, to keep entities in memory.  Spring beans have mulplie different [possible scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html).

Worth mentioning that keeping everything stateless makes scaling out easier. And adding state to anything http is always counter intuitive, to me at least.

Comment: I guess 2nd level cache is the best choice because Spring doesn't have the scopes like `Conversation` which can span arbitrary amount of requests. @NimChimpsky

Comment: @Neo conversational scope is availbale in spring-webflow http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/